# A form which will contain a list of students

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I want to understand how to create a form which will look like a "table of something". Here is what I mean:

[image]

Above is a screenshot from "Students" template (one of built-in templates of Access 2016). So, you can add new students here and easily edit any information. For example, you can change the "Level" of the student from "1st Grade" to "2nd".

Well, I understand that this form is attached to "Students" table:

[image]

But when I try to create some form myself, it doesn't contain a list of students. Instead, it contain the details of only one student:

[image]

How I can achieve the desired result, shown on the 1st image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for form's Default View `Datasheet` or `Continuous Forms` instead of `Single Form` you used.

Comment: Thank you very much. To be honest, I supposed it will be much harder :)